# Conversão Python para C++

Tags: python, c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, variáveis

Trabalho no meu curso com C++, e queria usar um recurso de acesso a variáveis da classe do Python. Veja um exemplo:

```
class Telefone:
    nums = {}

    def __init__(self, numero):
        self.num = numero
        Telefone.nums[numero] = self
        print(list(Telefone.nums))


joao = Telefone(40028922)  
paulo = Telefone(30302020)  
pedro = Telefone(55677655)
```

Saída:

```
[40028922]
[40028922, 30302020]
[40028922, 30302020, 55677655]
```

Como faço isso no C++?

Comment: Não entendi - você quer um recurso similar ao demonstrado em c++?

Comment: podes usar isto:
Shred Skin que e um compilador de python para c++; espero ter ajudado

Comment: @Blogueira, sim, queria fazer algo parecido em c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que não existe maneira simples de implementar isso em C++. Certas features de linguagens como Python só podem ser expressadas em C++ com hacks ou lógicas complicadas. Mas você poderia fazer assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;


class Telefone
{
    using num_map = unordered_map<string, Telefone>;

    static num_map nums;

public:
     Telefone()  { }

    Telefone(const string& numero)
    {
        nums[numero] = *this;
         Print();
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "[ ";
        for (const auto& num : nums)
            cout << num.first << " ";
        cout << "]\n";
    }
};

Telefone::num_map Telefone::nums;


int main()
{
    Telefone joao("40028922");
    Telefone epaulo("30302020");
    Telefone pedro("55677655");

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Se eu fosse você, tentaria escrever isso de uma forma mais simples usando corretamente os recursos do C++ ao invés de tentar imitar o comportamento do Python. Obs: eu usei string para representar o número porque a implementação de hash table do Visual C++(`std::unordered_map`) falha em manter a ordem dos valores com inteiros.